# Packing jar file into exists jar file

Tags: java, swing, file, jar, look-and-feel

I'm writing a MP3 player in Java.
If i will finish I want to pack all `.class` files in one `.jar` file. I don't want have player, which starts by console. 
If i open this one .jar file i want see player window.

I know how to pack it. I must use `jar.exe` packer with params: `cvfm Player.jar MANIFEST.MF ./config/*.class` and create `MANIEST.MF` which content class that has main method.

But the problem is when I want use another Look and Feel, or use existing .jar file. I can put this existing `.jar` file into my player main dir and compile `javac.exe` with parameter `-cp .;./JarFile.jar`, but when I pack all compiled `.class` files and my existsing `JTattooDebug.jar` file into one `Player.jar` file i don't see new Look and Feel i just see default view.

Comment: this is not in any way an answer but have you ever looked at maven?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any IDE I'm just running on .bat files. I know that i should using Eclipse, but first i need to know how to use.

Comment: You've described a problem, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question?

Comment: How to set JTattooDebug Look and Feel (not default) in packed Player.jar file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse.

Right-Click your project

```
Export -> Runnable Jar File
```

Then select the destination for your jar, and make sure you have "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" selected.  That will give you a runnable jar, complete with auto generated manifest, with all of your needed jars inside.

Comment: I'm not using any IDE I'm just running on .bat files. I know that i should using Eclipse, but first i need to know how to use.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I had to add line:

`Class-Path: lib/JTattooDebug.jar`

in my `MANIFEST.MF` file, now all works.